# Opera 12.16 required circular images produced oval

Tags: css, opera, zurb-foundation

I am creating a theme for a client of mine, and he gave a design that require some rounded images with border and shodow.

The problem is in Opera, that produces oval shapes instead of circular images.

Here is the result produced by Opera :

[image]

and this is the required result, and what the Chrome for example produce:

[image]

My HTML code is the following

```
<div class="row homeCategoryImageLinks">
    <div class="columns large-3 small-6 medium-6 ">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="oil.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="columns large-3 small-6 medium-6 ">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="oinopoioa.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="columns large-3 hide-for-small hide-for-medium ">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="athairia.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="columns large-3 hide-for-small hide-for-medium ">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="meli.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS Code:

```
.homeCategoryImageLinks
{
    margin-top: -164px !important;
    z-index: 3500 !important;
    margin-bottom: 25px !important;
}

.homeCategoryImageLinks div.columns
{
    z-index: 3501;
}

.homeCategoryImageLinks a
{
    z-index: 3502;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 55%;
    display: table;
}

.homeCategoryImageLinks a img
{
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: table-row;
    width : 100%;
}
```

The whole project is based on Foundation framework, thus some classes in HTML elements are related to Foundation framework.

Here you can find a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezG9Z/1/)** of my code.

**UPDATE 1**

This is the result when I hover the column a level above the  element in inspection mode of the Opera.

[image]

It seams like the anchor resized horizontaly but not vertically.

Comment: Which version of Opera? I've tested in Opera 17 and it seems to be normal.

Comment: I have 12.16. Is it too old ? :? Also I have notice that the code in Fiddle works fine on my Opera, but not in my theme :? What's wrong with that ?

Comment: Actually it is little old. Opera now uses the new rendering engine from Google (Blink) so if the code works in Chrome, should be equal in Opera 15+.

Comment: I just used the update process of Opera and says it is the latest version xaxaxaxa Cool eh !!! :)

Comment: Is your page rendering in standards mode?

Comment: How can I check the Opera mode ? I think operates in default settings.

Comment: Thats because Opera redesigned most of its browser based on Chromium and Blink, which means that the only way to get the new version is to download it from site. So now there are two "versions" of Opera. The old one, that went to version 12 and was based on Opera's own rendering engine, and the new one, which are based on Blink.

Comment: I just download the new version, let's see what is the result.

Comment: Oh got !! The diference is huge .... !!!!

Comment: As far as Opera is concerned, anything beyond version 12 is irrelevant.  Opera users are not upgrading because the versions using the Blink rendering engine have virtually none of the features they've come to expect from the browser.  The fact that the problem cannot be reproduced in jsfiddle shows that you have other code causing the problem.

Comment: How old is the version 12 ? I mean, can I say to my client that this version is really too old ? Is like saying it is IE7 ? Or should I fix that issue ?

Comment: Opera 12.15 was released on 2013-04-04 (see: http://www.opera.com/docs/history/presto/#o1215)

Comment: Oh !! I see, so it is not so old. Propably I have to fix the CSS Issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `box-sizing` to `border-box` on the links.

```
homeCategoryImageLinks a
{
    z-index: 3502;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 55%;
    display: table;

    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

I am thinking the problem is that you add padding to the links and then set the width of the image to 100% so it will include the padding which will in turn expand the link..

---

Alternatively you could add a border of 5 pixels to the image instead of padding to the link..

**Update**

Try

```
.homeCategoryImageLinks a
{
    z-index: 3502;
    display: table;
}

.homeCategoryImageLinks a img
{
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: table-row;
    width : 100%;
    border:5px solid white;


    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.45);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunatelly no diference :(

Comment: :( i will have a look in 10mins, when i have access to opera.. also if you have a live demo, it would be ideal so we can actually work on..

Comment: Unfortunatelly the site still in my local web server. If you see my initial message, I have set a demo in jsfiddle. But in fiddle works fine, in my local installation is the issue.

Comment: @MerianosNikos added an update about transferring the important CSS to the `img` instead of the `a` and clearing the `a` of unwanted , now, rules..

Comment: now I have compatibility problems with Safari, that dose not sizing the .homeCtegoryImageLinks a and I get as result only a bordered dot. Is there any solution to that :?